# Cannot assign value of type 'NSObject' file to type 'UIImage' - Apple Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create a photo album via UIImagePicker into a CollectionView and cannot get it to segue to said photo again in a detailed UIViewController. Pulling my hair out and this is just a tutorial as I have just started coding!

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var testItems = [Person]()

@IBAction func addItem() {
    addNewPerson()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailSegue" {
        if let dest = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController,
            let index = sender as? IndexPath {
                dest.detailedImageHi = testItems[index.row]
            }
    }
}
```

THE NS OBJECT FILE IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
class Person: NSObject {

    var imageHi: String

    init(imageHi: String){
        self.imageHi = imageHi
    }
}
```

DetailsViewController:
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

```
var selection: String!
var detailedImageHi: UIImage!


@IBOutlet private weak var detailsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var detailedImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    detailsLabel.text = selection
    detailedImage.image = detailedImageHi
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectionImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: You are not showing the declaration of `DetailsViewController` (especially its property `detailedImageHi`), `testItems`. It's hard to say what's happening or how to fix it without such info.

Comment: @OOPer - Many thanks for trying to help me! I wasn't sure anyone would be bothered. Sorry for not offering enough detail. Stack Overflow was being very fussy about what it would publish but I'm getting the hang of it now. Have added the Array 'testItems' and the DetailsViewController file and another VC associated with the cell called CollectionViewCell.

Comment: Does anyone else have an idea as to fix my Swift problem above? I took @OOPer advice and added more content to view. Any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As you see the Element type of `testItems` is `Person` and the type of the property is `UIImage!`. You cannot assign an instance of `Person` to a property of type `UIImage!`. What does `imageHi` of your `Person` contains? You may need to clarify a little more.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks so much for replying again!! The 'Person' that I have contained in the List item testItems is a class including an NSObject. Code is shown above. imageHi of the Person class is of type String - I tried to change this to a UIImageView but had no success wit that either. Once again thanks.